# Switch Ethernet Port Groups

Tags: switching

I am setting up a motion capture system (vicon vantage), and the cameras are PoE, and all plug into a switch (DGS‑1026MP, 26 Port Gigabit Max PoE Switch) to feed a PC.

The instructions say to not plug in the cameras into the upper right port of each group of four ports (see picture) and to reserve those ports for the PC or other switches. Is there a reason for this? I thought switches treated all ports as equivalent?

[image: the wrong ports])

Comment: I read through the manual and didn't see anything like that.

Comment: To which instructions are you referring? Could you provide a link to a digital copy? The manual for the DGS-1026MP makes no such statement.

Comment: Nothing is mentioned in User manual...

Comment: Its for the Vicon reference (https://www.vicon.com/downloads/documentation/vicon-vantage-reference), page 86

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

All ports are treated equal, however, in case of PoE, it is important to understand that PoE switches typically cannot power **all** ports at their maximum power at the same time.

I.e. NETSWITCH-24POE-2 recommended by Vicon provides up to 15.4W of power per port, but only 190W in total, meaning only 12 ports can supply full power PoE at the same time. It is possible that each group of 4 ports has its own power limit, hence the recommendation that you use one of the ports in the group for a non-PoE connection.

Your DGS‑1026MP switch has a total output of 370W so if your cameras use up to 15W you are safe to use any and all ports for your cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Vicon are referring to their own switch. That one seems to have a port power limit in each group of four (without making this very clear). With another switch you need to refer to the switch's documentation.

A PoE switch usually has a power limit per port and in total/over all ports. Some switches have additional limits for port groups.

Note that Vicon Vantage cameras require PoE+ ports (25.5 W). The DGS‑1026MP delivers up to 370 W, so it should be fine with up to 14 cameras (potentially more when considering the 25.5 W as peak).